# How to calculate the percentage of a specific color in an image?

Tags: image-processing, color

I have black-and white picture like this:
[image: spots]
Can anyone tell me if it's possible to calculate the area that black color occupies in this picture, so I know what's the percentage that black color has in the whole picture?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Maybe ImageMeasurements[] and if not then ImageData[]

Comment: Nitpick: you don't seek a surface (like a hyperboloid of one sheet), but an area (like 1.2 square millimetres).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After reading Michael E2's answer, I realized that one can simply do

```
1 - Mean[img]
```

> 0.106198

There are several other solutions as well. There is a function called `ImageLevels` that counts the channels:

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/PdMDk.png"];
levels = ImageLevels[img]
```

> {{0, 521982}, {1, 4393218}}

```
levels[[1, 2]]/(levels[[1, 2]] + levels[[2, 2]]) // N
```

> 0.106198

One could also use

```
neg = ColorNegate[img];
Total[neg, 2]/(Total[img, 2] + Total[neg, 2])
```

> 0.106198

or

```
{w, h} = ImageDimensions[img];
1 - Total[img, 2]/(w h)
```

> 0.106198

One could also explicitly get the matrix of image pixels:

```
pixels = Flatten@ImageData[img];
1 - Total[pixels]/Length[pixels] // N
```

> 0.106198

Answer (score 5):

Just use ImageHistogram with two levels:

```
ImageHistogram[myImage,2, FrameTicks->True]
```

[image]

or

```
Dimensions[SplitBy[ImageData[myImage], First]][[2;;3]]
```

(*

{886, 1342}

*)

Comment: So the percentage of black color is (886/1342)*100%

Answer (score 5):

For a binary image:

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/PdMDk.png"];
1 - ImageMeasurements[img, "MeanIntensity"]
(*  0.106198  *)
```

Comment: Thanks to this I realized that `1 - Mean[img]` works...

Comment: @C.E. Cool.  I didn't know that.